MySQL Unable to Login as root with credentials in ~/.my.cnf but credentials work with -p
For some reason suddenly I have to supply a password for MySQL. I checked ~/.my.cnf and the exact password is in there - in fact, I re-pasted it just to make sure. This is mysql 8.0.33 Community Server. I'm not sure what changed or when, because I already had my.cnf setup when it started failing. I know the file is being used, because if I mess with the [client] section, I get errors.. Now.. if I try to set options in a [mysqld] section nothing works, but that's beside my question.
Any ideas of what to check?
To be clear, connecting with: mysql -uroot -p and entering the same password when prompted, works.
mysql> select user, host, plugin from mysql.user where User='root'
    -> ;
+------+-----------+-----------------------+
| user | host      | plugin                |
+------+-----------+-----------------------+
| root | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
+------+-----------+-----------------------+


OK I figured it out, I was doing everything right but had changed the password and it had "special" characters in it such as percent signs. I didn't realize I needed double quotes until I saw an example of the file from the documentation (though from 5.7, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html):
Here is a typical user option file:
[client]
# The following password is sent to all standard MySQL clients
password="my password"

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
connect_timeout=2

Once I added the double-quotes, everything worked as it should have.
